# Call function in domain Many2one field

Tags: odoo, odoo-9

Is it possible call functin in domain Many2one field?

For example:

```
time = fields.Many2one('my.time', #call function here)
```

The time field is populated from database table my_time. In table I have several row:

```
id name

1  10:00

2  11:00

3  12:00

4. 13:00
```

In other table my_booked_time, I insert id (1) from time field, now I need filter Many2one "Select all available time (11:00,12:00,13:00)" not 10:00, where user_id = self.user_id and partner_id = self.partner_id

Any simple solution?

Comment: Why you don't add a Boolean field in my_time table to define if the time is blocked or not

Answer (score 2, accepted):

define domain on many2one let say that the  `my_booked_time` has m2o to table `my_time` named `time_id`:

```py
m2o_field = fields.Many2one(...., 
   domain=lambda self: [("id", "not in", self.env['my.booked.time'].search([]).mapped("time_id").ids)])
```

Comment: Tnx, how add in your example user_id = self.user_id and partner_id = self.partner_id

Comment: `lambda self: [('use_id','=', self.env.user.id), ('partner_id','=', self.env.user.partner_id.id)]`  what do you mean by partner id

Comment: i think user_id && partner_id if the first is true the second is true and the inverse ?